How to rewrite SOQL queries outside the loop in fetchVariablesFromHtml method?
type here
global class CampaignProcessor implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
     
        //fetching Campaign object records        
        List<Campaign_vod__c> campaigns = [SELECT Id, Name, Status_vod__c, Product_vod__c FROM Campaign_vod__c WHERE Start_Date_vod__c<=:Date.today() AND End_Date_vod__c >:Date.today()];
        
        
        // creating a list to store message records that need to be inserted        
        List<Sent_Message_vod__c> messageList = new List<Sent_Message_vod__c>();        
        
        //creating a new set to store campaign IDs        
        Set<Id> campaignIds = new Set<Id>();

        for(Campaign_vod__c campaign:campaigns)
            {
                campaignIds.add(campaign.Id);
            }
         DateTime now = DateTime.now();
         Time nowTime=now.time();
        
        System.debug(nowTime);
        //querying campaign activity records which are looking up to some campaign from the set, with a filter if the schedule datetime is equal to todays date
        List<Campaign_Activity_vod__c> activities = [SELECT Id, Name, Campaign_vod__c, Template_Doc_Number_AZ__c, Email_Source_vod__c, Scheduled_Send_Datetime_vod__c, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Campaign_Activity_vod__c WHERE Campaign_vod__c IN :campaignIds AND Scheduled_Send_Datetime_vod__c >= :System.today() AND Scheduled_Send_Datetime_vod__c < :System.today().addDays(1)];
        System.debug(activities.size());
        
        //querying campaign target records which are looking up to some campaign from the set
        List<Campaign_Target_vod__c> targets = [SELECT Id, Target_Account_vod__c, Campaign_vod__c, External_Id_vod__c, Target_Owner_User_vod__c, Territory_vod__c, Target_Account_vod__r.Secondary_Mobile__c, Target_Account_vod__r.Id, Target_Owner_User_vod__r.Id,Target_Account_vod__r.Country_Code_AZ__c, Target_Owner_User_vod__r.Name, Target_Account_vod__r.Name FROM Campaign_Target_vod__c WHERE Campaign_vod__c IN :campaignIds];
        
    
         Map<Id, List<Campaign_Activity_vod__c>> activityRecordsByCampaignId = new Map<Id, List<Campaign_Activity_vod__c>>();
         Map<Id, List<Campaign_Target_vod__c>> targetRecordsByCampaignId = new Map<Id, List<Campaign_Target_vod__c>>();
    
    
        //storing list campaign activities corresponding to their campaign Id in a map
        for(Campaign_Activity_vod__c activity: activities)
            {
                if(!activityRecordsByCampaignId.containsKey(activity.Campaign_vod__c))
                {
                 activityRecordsByCampaignId.put(activity.Campaign_vod__c, new List<Campaign_Activity_vod__c>());
                }
                activityRecordsByCampaignId.get(activity.Campaign_vod__c).add(activity);
                
            }
        
        //storing list of campaign targets corresponding to their campaign Id in a map
        for(Campaign_Target_vod__c target: targets)
            {
                if(!targetRecordsByCampaignId.containsKey(target.Campaign_vod__c))
                {
                 targetRecordsByCampaignId.put(target.Campaign_vod__c, new List<Campaign_Target_vod__c>());
                }
                targetRecordsByCampaignId.get(target.Campaign_vod__c).add(target);
            }
        
        //querying document library object to populate doc library related fields in sent message
        List<AZ_Document_Library__c> documents = [Select Id, Name, AZ_Document_Number__c, AZ_Market__c , AZ_Thumbnail_Link__c, AZ_Media_URL__c, AZ_Email_html__c, AZ_Product__r.Id, AZ_Twillio_Document_External_ID__c FROM AZ_Document_Library__c];
            String documentNumber;
            String documentMediaUrl;
            String documentThumbnailLink;
            String documentId;
            String documentMarket;
            String documentHtml;
            String documentProduct;
            String documentExternalId;
            
        
         // querying user territory object to populate territory field in sent message
         List <UserTerritory2Association> territoryList=[SELECT Id, User.Name, Territory2.Id, UserId FROM UserTerritory2Association];    
         String territoryId;
            for(Campaign_vod__c campaign: campaigns)
            {
             
             //fetching all the campaign activities and targets corresponding to their campaign ids and storing in a list
             //to iterate over it
             List<Campaign_Activity_vod__c> relatedActivities = activityRecordsByCampaignId.get(campaign.Id);
             List<Campaign_Target_vod__c> relatedTargets=targetRecordsByCampaignId.get(campaign.Id);
             
             if(relatedActivities!=null && relatedTargets!=null)
            {
                
                for(Campaign_Activity_vod__c  relatedActivity: relatedActivities)
                {
                    for(AZ_Document_Library__c document : documents)
                    {
                        //fetching document number from campaign activity field and storing the data in variables to 
                        //populate sent message record below
                        if(document.AZ_Document_Number__c==relatedActivity.Template_Doc_Number_AZ__c)
                        {
                            documentNumber=document.AZ_Document_Number__c;
                            documentMarket=document.AZ_Market__c;
                            documentMediaUrl=document.AZ_Media_URL__c;
                            documentThumbnailLink=document.AZ_Thumbnail_Link__c;
                            documentId=document.Id;
                            documentHtml=document.AZ_Email_html__c;
                            documentProduct=document.AZ_Product__r.Id;
                            documentExternalId=document.AZ_Twillio_Document_External_ID__c;
                        }
                    }
                
                
                    for(Campaign_Target_vod__c relatedTarget: relatedTargets)
                    {
                        for(UserTerritory2Association territories:territoryList )
                        {
                            if(territories.UserId==relatedTarget.Target_Owner_User_vod__r.Id)
                            {
                                territoryId=territories.Territory2.Id;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if(relatedActivity.Scheduled_Send_Datetime_vod__c!=null)
                        {
                          Date scheduleDate = relatedActivity.Scheduled_Send_Datetime_vod__c.Date();
                          Time scheduleTime=relatedActivity.Scheduled_Send_Datetime_vod__c.time();
                         
                         //if(scheduleDate==Date.today() && nowTime.minute()==scheduleTime.addMinutes(-60).minute() && nowTime.hour()==scheduleTime.addMinutes(-60).hour())
                            
               
                            if(scheduleDate==Date.today())
                            {
                                //creating a new sent message object record and populating the fields from
                                //campaign data
                                Sent_Message_vod__c message = new Sent_Message_vod__c();
                                System.debug(campaign.Name);
                                message.Account_vod__c=relatedTarget.Target_Account_vod__r.Id;
                                message.Status_vod__c = 'Saved_AZ';
                                message.AZ_From_Number__c= captureFromNumber(relatedTarget.Target_Account_vod__r.Id, relatedTarget.Target_Owner_User_vod__r.Id, documentMarket);
                                message.AZ_To_Number__c = relatedTarget.Target_Account_vod__r.Secondary_Mobile__c;
                                message.Product_vod__c = documentProduct;
                                message.AZ_Document_Library__c=documentId;
                                message.Territory_vod__c=territoryId;
                                if(relatedActivity.RecordType.DeveloperName.contains('SMS'))
                                    message.RecordTypeId='0123o000001USIEAA4';
                                else
                                {
                                message.RecordTypeId='0123o000001USIFAA4';
                                message.AZ_Template_ContentSid__c=documentExternalId;
                                message.AZ_Messaging_Service_SID__c=messagingService(documentMarket);
                                message.AZ_From_Number__c='whatsapp:' +message.AZ_From_Number__c;     
                                message.AZ_To_Number__c='whatsapp:' +message.AZ_To_Number__c;
                                }
                                message.AZ_Country_Code__c=documentMarket;
                                message.AZ_Message_Body__c=fetchVariablesFromHtml(documentHtml, relatedTarget.Target_Account_vod__r.Id, relatedTarget.Target_Owner_User_vod__r.Id, documentId);
                                //message.AZ_Message_Body__c=populateMessageBody(documentHtml, relatedTarget.Target_Account_vod__r.Id, relatedTarget.Target_Owner_User_vod__r.Id);
                                message.AZ_Mobile_Number_Type__c = mobileNumberType(relatedActivity.Email_source_vod__c);
                                message.AZ_Thumbnail_Link__c=documentThumbnailLink;
                                message.Media_URL_AZ__c=documentMediaUrl;
                                //message.AZ_Template_ContentVariables__c='{"1": "Swetha Iyer","2": "gareth.rayner@astrazeneca.com.invalid"}';
                                message.AZ_Direction__c='outbound-api';
                                message.Transaction_Type_vod__c='Text_Content';
                                System.debug(relatedActivity.Name);
                                System.debug(message);
                                messageList.add(message);
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                    
                }
            }
            }
                       //insert messageList;
    
            }
            
   
    
List<AZ_Authorized_Number_Mapping__c> numberMappingsForPair= [SELECT Id, AZ_Account__c, AZ_Field_Rep__c, AZ_Authorized_Number__c, AZ_Country_Code__c FROM AZ_Authorized_Number_Mapping__c]; 
List<AZ_Authorized_Numbers__c> numbersInPool= [SELECT Id, AZ_Allocated_Number__c, AZ_Country_Code__c FROM AZ_Authorized_Numbers__c]; 
List<Message_vod__c> veevaMessagesList = [select Id, Name, Text_vod__c from Message_vod__c where name like '%Content_API%'];
  
    public String fetchVariablesFromHtml(String emailBody, String HcpId, String RepId, String docId)
    {
        Map<String, String> variableMap = new Map<String, String>();     
        Integer startIndex = 0;
        while (startIndex < emailBody.length()) {
            Integer openBraceIndex = emailBody.indexOf('{{', startIndex);
                if (openBraceIndex == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            Integer closeBraceIndex = emailBody.indexOf('}}', openBraceIndex);
                if (closeBraceIndex == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            String variable = emailBody.substring(openBraceIndex, closeBraceIndex + 2);
            String objectField = variable.substring(2, variable.length() - 2);
            variableMap.put(variable, objectField);
            startIndex = closeBraceIndex + 2;
            }
        
            Map<String, String> fieldValueMap = new Map<String, String>();
            Set<String> accountFields = new Set<String>();
            Set<String> userFields = new Set<String>();
        
            for (String variable : variableMap.keySet()) {
            String objectField = variableMap.get(variable);
            String[] parts = objectField.split('\\.');
            String objectName = parts[0];
            String fieldName = parts[1];
            String query='';
            
                if(objectName=='Account')
                {
                    accountFields.add(fieldName); 
                    //query = 'SELECT ' + fieldName + ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE '+ objectName + '.Id=:HcpId';
                }
                else if(objectName=='User')
                {
                     userFields.add(fieldName);

                     //query = 'SELECT ' + fieldName + ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE '+ objectName + '.Id=:RepId';
                    
                }
                }
                
            Map<String, SObject> accountData = new Map<String, SObject>();
            Map<String, SObject> userData = new Map<String, SObject>();
        
        if (!accountFields.isEmpty()) 
        {
        String accountQuery = 'SELECT ' + String.join(new List<String>(accountFields), ', ') + ' FROM Account WHERE Id = :HcpId';
        accountData.put(HcpId, Database.query(accountQuery));
        }
    
        if (!userFields.isEmpty()) 
        {
        String userQuery = 'SELECT ' + String.join(new List<String>(userFields), ', ') + ' FROM User WHERE Id = :RepId';
        userData.put(RepId, Database.query(userQuery));
        }


            //SObject record = Database.query(query);
            //String fieldValue = String.valueOf(record.get(fieldName));
            
            //fieldValueMap.put(variable, fieldValue);
    
        for (String variable : fieldValueMap.keySet()) {
        String fieldValue = fieldValueMap.get(variable);
        emailBody = emailBody.replace(variable, fieldValue);
        emailBody = emailBody.replace('\\n','\n');
    
    }
        return emailBody;
    }
    
     public String messagingService(String hcpCountryCode)
     {
         String textCompare='Content_API_'+ hcpCountryCode;
         String messageServiceSID='';
         for(Message_vod__c veevaMsg : veevaMessagesList)
         {
             if(veevaMsg.Name==textCompare)
             { messageServiceSID=veevaMsg.Text_vod__c;
             }
       
         }
         return messageServiceSID;
       }
   public String populateMessageBody(String emailBody, String accountName, String repName)
    {
        if(emailBody!=null){
        emailBody = emailBody.replace('{{Account.Name}}',accountName);
        emailBody = emailBody.replace('{{User.Name}}',repName);
        emailBody = emailBody.replace('\\n','\n');
        }
        return emailBody;
     }
    public String captureFromNumber(Id HcpId, Id RepId, String HcpCountryCode)
    {
        Set<String> usedNumbersForHcp = new Set<String>();
        Set<String> totalNumbersAvailable=new Set<String>();

        //checking if HCP and Rep pair already exists, if yes then returning the number in use
        for(AZ_Authorized_Number_Mapping__c numberMapping:numberMappingsForPair)
        {
            if(numberMapping.AZ_Account__c==HcpId && numberMapping.AZ_Field_Rep__c==RepId)
            {
                System.debug('1st condition');

                return numberMapping.AZ_Authorized_Number__c;
            }
        }
        
        //getting total already used numbers for particular HCP from Authorized Number Mapping
        for(AZ_Authorized_Number_Mapping__c numberMapping:numberMappingsForPair)
        {
            if(numberMapping.AZ_Account__c==HcpId)
            {
                usedNumbersForHcp.add(numberMapping.AZ_Authorized_Number__c);

            }

        }
        
        //getting total numbers in authorized numbers for specific country
        for(AZ_Authorized_Numbers__c numberInPool:numbersInPool)
        {
            if(numberInPool.AZ_Country_Code__c ==HcpCountryCode)
            {
                totalNumbersAvailable.add(numberInPool.AZ_Allocated_Number__c);
            }

        }
        
        //if unused numbers are available in authorized, storing them in a set and retrieving a unique number
        if(usedNumbersForHcp.size()<totalNumbersAvailable.size())
        {
            Set<String> uniqueNumbersAvailable = new Set<String>(totalNumbersAvailable);
            uniqueNumbersAvailable.removeAll(usedNumbersForHcp);
            return new List<String>(uniqueNumbersAvailable).get(0);
        }
        else if(usedNumbersForHcp.size()!=0 && totalNumbersAvailable.size()!=0)
        {
            return new List<String>(totalNumbersAvailable).get(0);
        }
        else 
        return null;
    }
    
    public String mobileNumberType(String emailSource) {
        if(emailSource!=null)
        {
            String extractedPart = emailSource.substringAfter('.');
            String finalPart = extractedPart.substringBefore('_');
            return finalPart;
        }
        else
            return null;
        
    }
    
    
}

I'm gather data from a few objects and inserting the data in a new object. However, for some of the fields of the Sent_Message object, I need to write some logic to populate it. The method fetchVariablesFromHtml is inside a for loop, which means that my SOQL query inside it would be indirectly inside the for loop and hence I might end up hitting the governor limits. How can I refactor the particular method to achieve the same results without hitting governor limits?
The fetchVariables method is basically scanning a HTML document, fetching the variables which are in the format {{Object.Field}} constructing a dynamic query based on the values we get and replace the variables with the absolute values.
